# Plot of x^(1/3) has range of 0-inf in Mathematica and R

Tags: limits, mathematica, graphing-functions

Just doing a quick plot of the cuberoot of x, but both Mathematica 9 and R 2.15.32 are not plotting it in the negative space.  However they both plot x cubed just fine:

```
Plot[{x^(1/3), x^3}, 
    {x, -2, 2}, PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F3%29%2Cx%5E3

```
plot(function(x){x^(1/3)} , xlim=c(-2,2), ylim=c(-2,2))
```

Is this a bug in both software packages, or is there something about the cubed root that I don't understand?

```
In[19]:= {1^3, 1^(1/3), -1^3, -1^(1/3), 42^3, -42^3, 42^(1/3) // N, -42^(1/3) // N}
Out[19]= {1, 1, -1, -1, 74088, -74088, 3.47603, -3.47603}
```

Interestingly when passing -42 into the R function I get NaN, but when I multiply it directly I get -3.476027.

```
> f = function(x){x^(1/3)}
> f(c(42, -42))
[1] 3.476027      NaN
> -42^(1/3)
[1] -3.476027
```

Comment: In case you didn't know, there is also a [Mathematica stack exchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com).  See for example [Finding real roots of negative numbers](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8)

Comment: Look at a table of [*values*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=table%5Bx%5E%281%2F3%29%2C+%7Bx%2C-10%2C+10%7D%5D%2F%2FN). See the real and complex [*plot*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%5Bx%5E%281%2F3%29%2C+%7Bx%2C-5%2C+5%7D%5D)? Maybe that is your issue? Regards

Comment: Thanks Amzoti and Jonas I need to study more about the imaginary unit.  I think you should make those answers instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think: if $z < 0$, Mathematica is using the principal branch of the log along with the identity
$$z^{1/3} = \exp((1/3)*\log(z)).$$
If you use $z = -1$, you get
$$z^{1/3} = \text{e}^{(1/3)*\log(z)} = \text{e}^{\pi/3} = \exp(i\pi/3) = {1 + \sqrt{3}i\over 2}$$
In a word, the software is being "scrupulous to a fault."   It's a small price to pay for the program being so complex-number savvy.

Comment: I think you are missing an $i$ in your last equality, $(1+\sqrt{3}i)/2$.

Comment: @Daryl: Thanks. I edited it. :-)

Comment: very good detective work! +1

Answer (score 1):

Really funny you'd mention that... my Calc professor talked about that last semester. ;)

Many software packages plot the *principal root,* rather than the real root. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalRootofUnity.html

For example, $\sqrt[3]{3}$ has three values: [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%20=%203)

Mathematica uses the roots in the upper-left quadrant when plotting the cube root.  Thus, it thinks it's complex, and therefore doesn't graph it.

Comment: I reread my answer, and thought it needed a little clarification:  Mathematica doesn't use the roots in the upper-left quadrant *all* the time--rather, it uses the principal root (informally, the root with the lowest positive imaginary part).  This happens to occur in the upper-left quadrant for the cube root.

Answer (score 1):

If you merely want to *plot* the function, then you can be smarter. The function $x/|x|$ returns $1$ when $x\geq0$ and $-1$ otherwise. Thus, the function $\frac{x}{|x|}|x|^{1/3}$ has the same image as $x^{1/3}$ but it is defined over the whole domain $\mathbb{R}$.

See also [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144463/412).