# Wolfram Alpha gives wrongs answer for an equation

Tags: radicals, wolfram-alpha

I have experienced an issue while evaluating $$(x)^\frac{1}{5}-x = 0$$ The values that the program gives are 0 and 1, however, there is an additional solution, which is -1. In addition, the corrispondent graph is wrong because it excludes values of x for negative numbers. I have also noticed that when I try to evaluate:  $$(x)^\frac{1}{5}=-1$$ Wolfram Alpha gives no solutions, instead the solution should be -1 (over the reals). I believe that there  is a general problem in the program that comes up when trying to evaluate $$(x)^\frac{1}{n} , x<0, n = 2n+1, n = {1,2,3..}$$

Comment: It might be more productive to email Wolfram, we cannot change how it does its thing.

Comment: I don't see any question, here.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck There is a legitimate question in between the lines about `wolfram-alpha`, which is a valid MSE tag. To the OP: you may consider rephrasing the (mistaken) statement about "*wrong answer from WA*" into a question about "*where is the -1 root I expected*".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Mind the text right under the equation:

> Assuming the principal root  |  Use the real‐valued root instead

Click [the real-valued root](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E(1%2F5)+-+x+%3D+0&rawformassumption=%22%5E%22+-%3E+%22Real%22) and you get the $3$ real roots $\,\{-1,0,1\}\,$, and the graph over the entire $\mathbb{R}$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]  To clarify what happens under the default Wolfram Alpha interpretation of "*assuming the principal root*", the equation is taken to be in complex numbers, and $x^{\frac{1}{5}}$ is assumed to be the [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) of the $5^{th}$-root [complex power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers) function. With the usual choices for the [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts) along the negative real axis and the principal root being the one with the minimum argument, the principal value of $(-1)^{\frac{1}{5}}$ is $w = \text{cis}\;\frac{\pi}{5}$. This value does *not* satisfy the equality $w - w^5 = 0$ and therefore WA does not return it as a root of $x^{\frac{1}{5}} - x=0$ under the "*principal root*" interpretation.

For related discussion and insights see for example [What is the principal cubic root of −8?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306447/what-is-the-principal-cubic-root-of-8).

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining what is the principal root, which in this case would be $\cos \frac{pi}{5} + i\sin \frac{pi}{5}$, I believe?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Right. I edited some more into the answer.

Comment: Very informative! +1

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Are you serious?? There was the very obvious implied question "*why doesn't WA return -1 as a root*" which I replied to. A few fellow users even found the answer useful, apparently. I'd be curious to understand what you think the advantage would have been for MSE if I hadn't posted any answer.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck The posted question is one word twist away from being a formally legitimate question. If that technicality bothers you so much, then I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: P.S. @TheGreatDuck or whoever downvoted, I don't think that's a wise use of downvotes on answers. FWIW I put my stand on that up for discussion on [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25329/downvoting-answers-because-the-question-was-deemed-unfit).