# What is $\sqrt[4]{-1}$

Tags: complex-numbers

So, we all know that $\sqrt{-1}=i$, that $\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt2i$, and so on. And that, for example, $\sqrt[3]{-27}=-3$. But I was wondering; what would $\sqrt[4]{-1}$ be? Since all $n^{th}$ roots of $-1$ that are odd result in $-1$ (Because $-1^{1,3,5,7,9,\dots}=-1$), I wondered what variation of $i$ would even roots of $-1$ give? (Like $\sqrt{-1},\sqrt[4]{-1},\sqrt[6]{-1},\dots$)

Comment: You're wrong:  $\sqrt{-2} \neq 2 i$.

Comment: So what does it equal?

Comment: $\sqrt{-4}=2i$.  Meanwhile $\sqrt{-2}=(\sqrt{2})i$

Comment: As for $\sqrt[3]{-27}$, that depends on what you mean by $\sqrt[3]{~}$.  The *real* root of $\sqrt[3]{-27}$ will indeed be $-3$, however the *principle* root (*being the root with the smaller argument*) will instead be $3(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}i}{2})$.  Some people intend $\sqrt[n]{~}$ to mean the real root if it exists and only if it doesnt for $\sqrt[n]{~}$ to mean the root with smallest argument.  Others intend $\sqrt[n]{~}$ to *always* mean the root with smallest argument.

Comment: Check out the "Some Sample Fractional Powers of i" in my blog article https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/754.php for the square root of i.  Do the same thing for -i and you will have all four answers.

Comment: I’m talking about the real root, as I have not learned the difference between a real root and a principle root.

Comment: If you mean real root only, then why consider $i$?  It is not real.  If you consider only the real root, then why don't you say that $\sqrt{-1}$ 
"doesn't exist"?

Comment: Because, to some extent, I understand and can work with complex numbers without the principle roots

Comment: Shouldn't the title be $\sqrt [4] {-1}$ as opposed to $\sqrt [4] {i}$ by the way?

Comment: Oops didn’t see that. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Related to my earlier points: [what is the principal cubic root of 8](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306447/what-is-the-principal-cubic-root-of-8/)

Comment: You shouldn't write $-1^3$ if you mean $(-1)^3.$ Those are two different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would $\sqrt{-1}=i$ and not $\sqrt{-1}=-i$? There is no real reason to choose.

What we do is to enumerate the roots; there are two square roots, three cubics roots, four fourth roots, etc.

From $-1=\cos\pi+i\sin\pi$, we can deduce via [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) (or using $-1=e^{i\pi}$), that the four fourth roots of $-1$ are 
$$
\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}4+i\sin\frac{(2k+1)\pi}4,\ \ k=0,1,2,3.
$$
Explicitly, you have 
$$
\cos\frac\pi4+i\sin\frac\pi4=\frac1{\sqrt2}+i\,\frac1{\sqrt2},
$$
$$
\cos\frac{3\pi}4+i\sin\frac{3\pi}4=-\frac1{\sqrt2}+i\,\frac1{\sqrt2},
$$
$$
\cos\frac{5\pi}4+i\sin\frac{5\pi}4=-\frac1{\sqrt2}-i\,\frac1{\sqrt2},
$$
$$
\cos\frac{7\pi}4+i\sin\frac{7\pi}4=\frac1{\sqrt2}-i\,\frac1{\sqrt2}.
$$
Note that similarly there is no single cubic root of $-1$, but three of them:
$$
\cos\frac{(2k+1)\pi}3+i\sin\frac{(2k+1)\pi}3,\ \ k=0,1,2.
$$

Comment: Stupid question: Why are there four fourth roots? Or three cubic roots? There’s only one answer to, for example, the cubic root of -27, or the fifth root of -32. (I’m in Grade 7, so some things are too advanced for me.)

Comment: Not stupid at all. Any complex number $c$ has four fourth roots. One way to see it is that $1$ has four roots (that can be obtained as in my answer, they are equally spaced on the unit circle), and they are of the form $1,r,r^2,r^2$. So if now $x^4=c$, then $(rx)^4=r^4x^4=1c=c$.

Comment: @Detmondyou See the [Fundamental theorem of Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: my first version of the comment was about it. But the FTA will not tell you that the roots are not repeated. It will only tell you that there is a root.

Comment: Indeed, but it may help to point out that an n degree polynomial has n (possibly repeating) roots. It seems the OP is not very aware of that fact.

Comment: I was not, thank you for pointing it out. (Grade 7, remember?)

Comment: I do remember. And I wanted to congratulate you for asking these kind of questions at your age.

Answer (score 3):

Method 1 Hint:
Consider
$$z^4=i$$
where 
$$z=a+bi$$
with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Expand and compare coefficients.
(Tedious)

---

Method 2:

Consider
$$i=i \cdot1^k= \exp\left({\frac\pi2i}\right)\cdot\left(\exp(2\pi i )\right)^k=\exp\left({\frac\pi2i+2k\pi i}\right)$$
for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Let
$$z=\exp({\theta i})$$
such that
$$z^4=i$$
Then use the relation
$$\exp(\theta i)=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

So
\begin{align}
\exp(4\theta i)&= \exp\left({\frac\pi2i+2k\pi i}\right)\\
4\theta i&= \frac\pi2i+2k\pi i\\
\theta&=\frac\pi8+\frac\pi2k\\
\end{align}

Hence, the fourth roots of $i$ are
$$z=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$with
$$\theta= -\frac{7\pi} 8,-\frac{3\pi}8,\frac\pi8,\frac{5\pi}8$$
for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: This answer is also good, just not as clear as Martin Argerami.

Comment: Just a mention one needs to find $z^4=-1$ not $z^4=i$, so for the first one you need to solve $z^2=i$ and $z^2=-i$ which isn't that tedious

Answer (score 3):

We will use *Euler's Identity*, $$e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0,\tag1$$ or in particular, $$\begin{align} e^{i\theta} &= \cos\theta + i\sin\theta \\ &= \text{cis}\,\theta.\end{align}\tag2$$

---

From $(1)$, we get that $e^{i\pi} = -1$, thus $$\begin{align} \left(e^{(i\pi)/2}\right)^{1/2} &= e^{(i\pi)/4} \\ &= \sqrt [4] {-1}.\end{align}$$ Now, using $(2)$, by substituing $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$, we obtain the following result: $$\begin{align} \sqrt [4] {-1} &= \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\ \\ &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) \\ \\ &= \boxed{ \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(1+i\right). \ }\end{align}$$ See what pattern you can find now with the sequence, $\sqrt{-1}, \sqrt [4] {-1}, \sqrt [6] {-1},\ldots$