# Function Domain of cubic root

Tags: functions

Does the domain of the function $y=\sqrt[3]{x^3+1}$ include $x<-1$? If yes, why is Mathematica and Wolfram Alpha not plotting that part of the function?

Comment: Yes. And what do you mean Wolfram Alpha is not plotting the function for $x < -1$? Here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+cube+root+of+%28x%5E3+%2B+1%29&lk=4&num=1

Comment: Oh, I put (x^3+1)^(1/3). http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D++%28x%5E3+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F3%29

Comment: Click "Use the real-valued root instead". By default, Mathematica chooses [the convention that is compatible with complex arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_root#Complex_numbers).

Comment: possible duplicate of [cubic root of negative numbers](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25528/cubic-root-of-negative-numbers)  See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273149/plot-of-x1-3-has-range-of-0-inf-in-mathematica-and-r and on the Mathematica site, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/finding-real-roots-of-negative-numbers-for-example-sqrt3-8

Answer (score -1):

The function:

$y=(x^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Should include a domain of all real numbers because negative numbers also can have a cube root. So, yes, it should include $x \lt -1$. I'm not sure why those websites are acting up.